# How not to show seconds with toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, globalization

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString says that:

> **second**
>   The representation of the second. Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit".

What's the difference betweeen "numeric" and "2-digit"? What do I use to show nothing for seconds? I omitted the `second` option and it is still showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2-digit are 0 padded, whereas numeric is not. Not specifying the seconds (undefined) is how you omit them. However, you do need to specify that you want hours and seconds. Something like:

```
var date = new Date();
var options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
```

Comment: My issue was I left out the first parameter, thinking it would use the default. However, the first parameter is compulsory if the second (options) is to be used. To use the default locale instead of hardcoding, I need to specify `undefined` as the first parameter. Without the first parameter, the options is ignored even if it is supplied (as the only parameter).

Comment: this is not good, i want it to be removed for all format, not only en-us

Comment: the entire point of using toLocaleString() is so you can include a date...

Answer (score 0):

[This manual helped me understanding the date system hope it helps you too](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-date-system-format-or-two-digit-year-interpretation-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f)

> Microsoft Office Excel stores dates as sequential numbers that are called 
>   serial values. For example, in Microsoft Office Excel for Windows,
>   January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial
>   number 39448 because it is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900. Office
>   Excel stores times as decimal fractions because time is considered a
>   portion of a day. The decimal number is a value ranging from 0 (zero)
>   to 0.99999999, representing the times from 0:00:00 (12:00:00 A.M.) to
>   23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.).
>
> Because dates and times are values, they can be added, subtracted, and
>   included in other calculations. You can view a date as a serial value
>   and a time as a decimal fraction by changing the format of the cell
>   that contains the date or time to General format.

Another one will be :
[Mysql based interpretation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/two-digit-years.html)

> Date values with two-digit years are ambiguous because the century is unknown. Such values must be interpreted into four-digit form because MySQL stores years internally using four digits.
>
> For DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP types, MySQL interprets dates
>   specified with ambiguous year values using these rules:
>
> Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
>
> Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.
>
> For YEAR, the rules are the same, with this exception: A numeric 00
>   inserted into YEAR(4) results in 0000 rather than 2000. To specify
>   zero for YEAR(4) and have it be interpreted as 2000, specify it as a
>   string '0' or '00'.

I have used other documentations as reference here because there base
is same hope they help you as well.